# How to use scrapy to search in the search bar on amazon?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is probably a basic question? But how do I use scrapy to type something on the search bar on amazon? For example, the starting URL is just Amazon.com. I want scrapy to type in "iPhone 11 pro max" in the search bar and click search. I know how to **scrape** data once the response page is displayed. But not sure how to let scrapy automate the search? I'm not sure if FormRequest is what I should use. Could someone give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use URL like this in your scrapy project:

```
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={}'.format(your_keyword)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there similar links for other e-commerce websites? Like Ebay, or less well-known sites like Tmall? Do all e-commerce sites have something like this?

Comment: yeah, almost all e-commerce websites have a similar link.

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, but is there a name for this kind of links? How would you find these for different e-commerce sites?

Comment: click ```ctrl + shift +i ``` ic chrome > go to Network tab > try to search for something on the website and then monitor all requests to find a search request. This is the simplest way to find any links you want )

Comment: you should encode the query using `from urllib.parse import urlencode`